# asp.net gridview: How can I have multiple button fields in one column?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I need to create multiple actions for a gridview - say, "Approve", "Deny", and "Return".

I can do this by creating a button field for each action:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve" /> 
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Deny" Text="Deny /> 
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Return" Text="Deny" />
```

However, this creates one column for each button.

Is there a way to have the same functionality, but combine them into a single column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you considered using an `TemplateField`?  Here is an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTest" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeny" runat="server" CommandName="Deny" Text="Deny" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnReturn" runat="server" CommandName="Return" Text="Return" />
            </ItemTemplate>                
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can then capture the commands the exact same way using `OnRowCommand` or do whatever you like.  You have full control to make it behave how you need and not be bound by the built in functionality of using the regular predefined column types.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put buttons into the `<asp:TemplateField>` instead:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve" /> 
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Deny" Text="Deny /> 
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Return" Text="Deny" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is not to use ButtonField elements.

To accomplish what you want you will need to create a column as a `TemplateField` and define buttons as regular ASP.NET `<asp:Button id="myButton" />` within `TemplateField`'s `ItemTemplate` or `EditItemTemplate` as appropriate for your UI.

You can handle Click events in the `GridView_OnItemCommand()` handler, where you can check `e.CommandName` to figure out exactly which button caused the event.

Comment: Yes this is the correct solution. I was confused by LinkButtons and found out that asp:Button would replace asp:ButtonField when placed inside an ItemTemplace of TemplateField. Wish I had seen this answer first, before leaving the site!