# Merging Edit and Delete Columns in Radgrid

Tags: c#, merge, telerik, radgrid

Is there a way to merge these two columns? This is what I have right now 
[image]. This is how I created these two columns from code-behind

```
                        GridEditCommandColumn EditColumn = new GridEditCommandColumn();
                        this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(EditColumn);
                        EditColumn.ButtonType = GridButtonColumnType.ImageButton;
                        EditColumn.UniqueName = "EditCommandColumn";
                        EditColumn.HeaderText = "SingleAction";
                        EditColumn.ColumnGroupName = "test";

                        GridButtonColumn DeleteColumn = new GridButtonColumn();
                        this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(DeleteColumn);
                        DeleteColumn.CommandName = "Delete";
                        DeleteColumn.ButtonType = GridButtonColumnType.ImageButton;
                        DeleteColumn.UniqueName = "DeleteCommandColumn";
                        DeleteColumn.ConfirmDialogType = GridConfirmDialogType.Classic;
                        DeleteColumn.HeaderText = "SingleAction";
                        DeleteColumn.ConfirmText = "Do you really want to delete?";
```

Now I want to achieve something like this
[image]
I have tried to do the GridCalculatedColumn like this

`GridCalculatedColumn calcol = new GridCalculatedColumn();

 calcol.DataFields =new string[]{"EditCommandColumn","DeleteCommandColumn"};

 calcol.Expression ="{0}-{1}";

 tableViewProjects.Columns.Add(calcol);`

But, I cannot achieve what I want. I get an error column [EditCommandColumn] does not exist, which I think makes sense, because it not a data field from the database. 
 So, is there a way to achieve this.

Please help,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from the Telerik help. The link for the same is

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/merging-edit-and-delete-columns-in-radgrid.aspx

Thank  you all

Answer (score 0):

The telerik RadGrid is "some kind" of DataGrid and offers the same options

One of these options is the itemtemplate.

You can put any html-element in that template. This code is stolen from that answer:[asp.net gridview: How can I have multple button fields in one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120114/asp-net-gridview-how-can-i-have-multple-button-fields-in-one-column)

but should also work with telerik

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeny" runat="server" CommandName="Deny" Text="Deny" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnReturn" runat="server" CommandName="Return" Text="Return" />
            </ItemTemplate>
```

To get more "telerik specific" help, "radgrid itemtemplate" should help you on the telerik knowledgebase